# How url dispatcher include apps urls

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include                       
from django.contrib.auth import login                         
         urlpatterns = [
             path('admin/', admin.site.urls),    
             path('login/',include
             ('authorization.urls')),
         ]
```

My included `authorization/urls.py` file is followed

```
from django.urls import path                               
from . import views                                        

     urlpatterns = [
         path('login',views.login_name),
    ]
```

While i started to learn url dispatcher logic i much times faced with

```
The current path, login/login/, didn't 
match any of these.
```

As pointed in documentation

> Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

When i am trying to access my login page i see

```
Using the URLconf defined   
in forecast.urls, Django tried these     
URL patterns, in this order:
 admin/
 login/ login
The current path, login/, didn't match any of these.
```

As i see from traceback  and from documentation notes while inside path function included `include()` function. Path parse given arguments and by examplefrom my project  first of all path parse given url pattern **login** than when path face with include function its give parsed url pattern to included urls. Than when included urls.py parsed its face with another url pattern **login** its chain them **login/login** and give it to attached views function.

Here is my first question how i should specify url pattern while i need use include function

Am i understood correctly in included app.urls.py i shouldn't specify login pattern based on my example

Can anyone understand me how path include function work that i can debug it

Answer (score 1):

you have repeated 'login', so change it as follows, so it will be available on /login

```
 path('',include('authorization.urls')),
```